# Create a cruise ticket price calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I am new to JavaScript. I want to make a Cruise ship ticket price calculator based on these information. I have tried to make it but I don't know much about JavaScript so I got confused what to do. If anyone helps me to find out what I should write on the Script it'll be so helpfull.

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var island = document.getRBtnName("island").value;
    var returnfare = document.getElementByName("returnfare").value;
    var class = document.getRBtnName("class").value;
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("inserts")= island * class * returnfare;
    } 
    </script>
```

```html
<form id="buy">
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="49">
            Main Beach - Azkaban Island</label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="79">
            Main Beach - Amity Island </label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="109">
            Main Beach - Treasure Island </label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="89">
            Main Beach - Gilligan’s Island</label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="59">
            Main Beach - Skull Island</label>
          <br>
          <p>Click here if you will be purchasing a return fare
            <input type="checkbox" name="returnfare" id="returnfare" value="2">
          </p>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" value="2.5" name="class">
            First class </label>
          <br>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" value="1.5" name="class">
            Business class </label>
          <br>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="class">
            Economy class</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate" onClick="myFunction()">
          <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
```

Comment: What is `getRBtnName`?

Comment: And the question is ? What do you want to do with these infos ?

Comment: getRBtnName is get radio button name @giannus

Comment: The question is how can i make the JavaScript workable. I am making a Price calculator using these information. @Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used jQuery for fix your code, I have changed the javascript and the type of the button calculate: from type="submit" type="button"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="buy">
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="49">
            Main Beach - Azkaban Island</label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="79">
            Main Beach - Amity Island </label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="109">
            Main Beach - Treasure Island </label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="89">
            Main Beach - Gilligan’s Island</label>
          <br>
          <label id="radiolabel">
            <input type="radio" name="island" value="59">
            Main Beach - Skull Island</label>
          <br>
          <p>Click here if you will be purchasing a return fare
            <input type="checkbox" name="returnfare" id="returnfare" value="2">
          </p>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" value="2.5" name="class">
            First class </label>
          <br>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" value="1.5" name="class">
            Business class </label>
          <br>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="class">
            Economy class</label>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="button" name="submit" value="Calculate" id="calculate" onClick="myFunction()">
          <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
        <span id="inserts"></span>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {
                var island = $('input[name=island]:checked', '#buy').val();
                var myClass = $('input[name=class]:checked', '#buy').val();
                var returnfare = 1;
                if ($("#returnfare").prop('checked')) {
                    returnfare = 2;
                }
                var total = island * myClass * returnfare;
                $("#inserts").text(total);

            } 
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use many of library on internet. Googling I find this [link](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/#demo)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the round figure here's the JavaScript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {
       var island = $('input[name=island]:checked', '#buy').val();
                var myClass = $('input[name=class]:checked', '#buy').val();
                var returnfare = 1;
                if ($("#returnfare").prop('checked')) {
                    returnfare = 2;
                }

                var total = island * myClass * returnfare;
    if (total == '122.5', '197.5', '272.5', '222.5', '147.5', '88.5', '133.5', '163.5', '118.5', '73.5') {total = Math.round (total)
     total = total;
    } 
     alert("The cost of the cruise is $" + total);

            } 
   window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = myFunction;
}


        </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I dont have time to write the code to give you im sorry but what you need to do is give a specific id for the destinations like "destination" same id for all the destinations. Then an id for the checkbox, and  same ids for which class they want to ride.

Then make x y and z and set them to the value of the choice they have picked.
Then make another var named total and do * x+(x*y)+(x*z) and display the total onclick of submit.

I hope i was even a little bit helpful. Sorry again for not providing any code.

Comment: I have tried but I didn't understand what you've said. If you explain this more Then It would be more helpful to me. Thanks!